# TextField Values reset after returning from the Image Picker

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a form in which I am displaying User existing data in `Textfield` and there is a profile image upload option as well. So lets say If I edit some fields in the textbox and then upload image from using `imagePicker`, then the data resets and it shows the old values. I don't know how can I fix this

My Code is this :-

```
class ProfileVC: UIViewController, TopViewDelegate,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate,UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var topView: WATopView!
    @IBOutlet weak var firstName: WATextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var lastName: WATextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var email: WATextField!
//    @IBOutlet weak var password: WATextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var university: WATextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var graduationDate: WATextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var major: WATextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var homeTown: WATextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var industry: WATextField!
    @IBOutlet var profileImageView: WAImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var imagePickerButton:WAButton!

    var pickerView = UIPickerView()
    var uniList = [University]()
    var industryList = [Industry]()
    var selectedIndustry: Industry?
    var selectedUni: University?

    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    var base64StringOf_my_image = String()
    var prepCompressedImage: UIImage!
    var isDismissing: Bool = false
    let currentUser = User.getCurrentUser()

    var inputViews = UIView()
    let datePickerView = UIDatePicker()

    let profileLoader = ProfileLoader()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if fireNotification.pickedImage != nil {
            profileImageView.image = fireNotification.pickedImage!.circle
            self.prepCompressedImage = UIImage.compressImage(fireNotification.pickedImage, compressRatio: 0.9)
            base64StringOf_my_image = appUtility.base64StringOfImage(self.prepCompressedImage)
            fireNotification.pickedImage = nil
        }else {
            profileImageView.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: currentUser!.userImageURL), placeholderImage: UIImage(named:"no-image"))
            self.prepCompressedImage = UIImage.compressImage(profileImageView.image, compressRatio: 0.9)
            base64StringOf_my_image = appUtility.base64StringOfImage(self.prepCompressedImage)
        }
        pickerView.delegate = self
        pickerView.dataSource = self
        loadIndAndUni()
        topView.delegate = self
        disableEditing(false)
        if !(currentUser?.firstName.isEmpty)! {
            firstName.text = currentUser?.firstName
        }
        if !(currentUser?.lastName.isEmpty)! {
            lastName.text = currentUser?.lastName
        }
        if !(currentUser?.email.isEmpty)! {
            email.text = currentUser?.email
        }
        if !(currentUser?.uni_name.isEmpty)! {
            university.text = currentUser?.uni_name
        }
        if !(currentUser?.startGradDate.isEmpty)! {
            graduationDate.text = currentUser?.startGradDate
        }
        if !(currentUser?.major.isEmpty)! {
            major.text = currentUser?.major
        }
        if !(currentUser?.homeTown.isEmpty)! {
            homeTown.text = currentUser?.homeTown
        }
        if !(currentUser?.ind_name.isEmpty)! {
            industry.text = currentUser?.ind_name
        }
        imagePickerButton.userInteractionEnabled = false

    }

    func loadIndAndUni(){
        if fireNotification.uniList != nil {
            uniList = fireNotification.uniList!
        }else { self.loadUni()}
        if fireNotification.indList != nil {
            industryList = fireNotification.indList!
        }else {self.loadIndustries()}
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func editDoneButtonAction(sender: UIButton) {
        if sender.titleLabel?.text == "Edit" {
            topView.doneText = "Done"
//            PrepUtility.showAlertWithTitle("Edit", error: "You are going to submit data", OKButton: "Edit", VC: self)
            imagePickerButton.userInteractionEnabled = true
            disableEditing(true)
        }
        if sender.titleLabel?.text == "Done" {

//            PrepUtility.showAlertWithTitle("Done", error: "You are going to submit data", OKButton: "Done", VC: self)
            submitRequest()
            topView.doneText = "Edit"
            disableEditing(false)
        }
    }

    func submitRequest(){
        let (isValid , error) = validateFields()
        if !isValid {
            appUtility.showAlert(error!,VC: self)
            return
        }

        if (base64StringOf_my_image.isEmpty) {
            appUtility.showAlert("Please Select Image",VC: self)
            return
        }

        if PrepUtility.connectedToNetwork() {
            appUtility.loadingView(self, isHide: false)
            if selectedUni != nil {
                let indText = industry.text
                var selectedI: Industry?
                for t in industryList {
                    if t.ind_name == indText {
                        selectedI = t
                    }
                }

                let params = ["std_id":currentUser!.std_id,"std_f_name":firstName.text!,"std_l_name":lastName.text!,"std_grad_date":graduationDate.text!,"std_hometown":homeTown.text!,"std_major":major.text!,"uni_id":selectedUni!.uni_id,"std_img":["content_type": "image/png", "filename":"test.png", "file_data": base64StringOf_my_image],"ind_id":selectedI!.ind_id]
                    editProfile(params)
            }else {
                let uniText = university.text
                var selectedU: University?
                for t in uniList {
                    if t.uni_name == uniText {
                        selectedU = t
                    }
                }

                let indText = industry.text
                var selectedI: Industry?
                for t in industryList {
                    if t.ind_name == indText {
                        selectedI = t
                    }
                }

                if selectedU!.uni_id.boolValue {
                    let params = ["std_id":currentUser!.std_id,"std_f_name":firstName.text!,"std_l_name":lastName.text!,"std_grad_date":graduationDate.text!,"std_hometown":homeTown.text!,"std_major":major.text!,"uni_id":selectedU!.uni_id,"std_img":["content_type": "image/png", "filename":"test.png", "file_data": base64StringOf_my_image],"ind_id":selectedI!.ind_id]
                        editProfile(params)
                }
            }
        }else {
            appUtility.loadingView(self, isHide: true)
            appUtility.showNoNetworkAlert()
        }
    }

        func editProfile(params:[String:AnyObject]) {
            profileLoader.tryStudentProfileEdit(params, successBlock: { (user) in
                appUtility.loadingView(self, isHide: true)
                }, failureBlock: { (error) in
                    //                    appUtility.showAlert((error?.userInfo["NSLocalizedDescription"])! as! String, VC: self)
                    if let err = error?.userInfo["NSLocalizedDescription"] {
                        appUtility.showAlert(err as! String, VC: self)
                        appUtility.loadingView(self, isHide: true)
                    }else {
                        appUtility.loadingView(self, isHide: true)
                        appUtility.showAlert("Something went wrong", VC: self)
                    }
            })
        }

    func openMenu() {
        firstName.resignFirstResponder()
        lastName.resignFirstResponder()
//        email.resignFirstResponder()
//        password.resignFirstResponder()
        university.resignFirstResponder()
        graduationDate.resignFirstResponder()
        major.resignFirstResponder()
        homeTown.resignFirstResponder()
        industry.resignFirstResponder()

        self.mainSlideMenu().openLeftMenu()
    }

    //MARK:- Private Methods

    private func validateFields() -> (Bool , String?) {

        if !firstName.isValid() {
            hideView()
            return (false , "Please enter your First Name")
        }

        if !lastName.isValid() {
            hideView()
            return (false , "Please enter your Last Name")
        }

//        if !email.isValid() {
//            hideView()
//            return (false , "Please enter email")
//        }
//        
//        if email.isValid() {
//            hideView()
//            let text = email.text
//            if !(text!.hasSuffix(".edu")) {
//                return (false , "Please enter email that having .edu")
//            }
//            if !email.text!.isValidEmail() {
//                return (false , "Please Enter a valid email...")
//            }
//        }

        if !university.isValid() {
            hideView()
//            return (false , "Please select University")
        }

        if !homeTown.isValid() {
            hideView()
//            return (false , "Please enter address")
        }
//        if !password.isValid() {
//            return (false , "Please enter password")
//        }
//        
        return (true , nil)
    }

    private func showGradDatePicker() {
        //Create the view
        graduationDate.inputView = inputViews
        inputViews = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.height, self.view.frame.width, 240))
        inputViews.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        let datePickerView  : UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker(frame: CGRectMake(0, 40, 0, 0))
        datePickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Date
        inputViews.addSubview(datePickerView) // add date picker to UIView

        let doneButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake((self.view.frame.size.width/2) - (100/2), 0, 100, 50))
        doneButton.setTitle("Done", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        doneButton.setTitle("Done", forState: UIControlState.Highlighted)
        doneButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        doneButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.grayColor(), forState: UIControlState.Highlighted)

        inputViews.addSubview(doneButton) // add Button to UIView

        doneButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ScheduleVC.doneButton(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside) // set button click event
//        sender.inputView = inputView
        datePickerView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ScheduleVC.datePickerValueChanged(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
        self.view.addSubview(inputViews)
        datePickerValueChanged(datePickerView) // Set the date on start.
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5) {
            self.inputViews.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.height - 270, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 240)
        }
    }

    func doneButton(sender:UIButton) {
        hideView()
    }

    func hideView() {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.9) {
            self.inputViews.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y:0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 240)
            self.inputViews.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }

    func datePickerValueChanged(sender:UIDatePicker) {
//        isDateSet = true
        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
//        dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
//        dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle
        graduationDate.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(sender.date)
    }

    func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        if textField == university {
            self.resignFirstResponder(university)
            industry.tag = 1
            university.tag = 0
            graduationDate.tag = 1
            pickerViewToolBar(textField)
        }

        if textField == industry {

            self.resignFirstResponder(industry)
            industry.tag = 0
            university.tag = 1
            graduationDate.tag = 1
            pickerViewToolBar(textField)
        }

        if textField == graduationDate{

            industry.tag = 1
            university.tag = 1
            graduationDate.tag = 0

            self.resignFirstResponder(graduationDate)
            showGradDatePicker()
        }

        return true
    }

    private func disableEditing(boo: Bool) {
        firstName.enabled = boo
        lastName.enabled = boo
//        email.enabled = boo
//        password.enabled = boo
        university.enabled = boo
        graduationDate.enabled = boo
        major.enabled = boo
        homeTown.enabled = boo
        industry.enabled = boo
    }

    private func resignFirstResponder(textField:UITextField) {
        if textField != firstName {
//            hideView()
            textField.resignFirstResponder()
        }
        if textField != lastName {
//            hideView()
            textField.resignFirstResponder()
        }
//        if textField != email{
////            hideView()
//            textField.resignFirstResponder()
//        }
//        if textField != password {
////            hideView()
//            textField.resignFirstResponder()
//        }
        if textField != university {
//            hideView()
            textField.resignFirstResponder()
        }
        if textField != graduationDate {
            textField.resignFirstResponder()
        }
        if textField != major {
//            hideView()
            textField.resignFirstResponder()
        }
        if textField != homeTown {
//            hideView()
            textField.resignFirstResponder()
        }
        if textField != industry {
//            hideView()
            textField.resignFirstResponder()
        }
    }

    private func resignAllTextFields() {
        firstName.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    //MARK:- Public Methods
    func pickerViewToolBar(sender: UITextField) {
        var doneButton:UIBarButtonItem?
        if university.tag == 0 {
            university.inputView = pickerView
        }
        if industry.tag == 0 {
            industry.inputView = pickerView
        }
        if graduationDate.tag == 0 {
            graduationDate.inputView = pickerView
        }
//        departureDatePickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Date

        // Sets up the "button"

        // Creates the toolbar
        let toolBar = UIToolbar()
        toolBar.barStyle = .Default
        toolBar.translucent = true
        toolBar.tintColor = UIColor(red: 92/255, green: 216/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1)
        toolBar.sizeToFit()

        // Adds the buttons
        if(sender.tag == 0){
            //            self.nextButton?.hidden = true
            doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .Plain, target: self, action: #selector(PrepInfoVC.doneClick(_:)))
            doneButton!.tag = 0
        }
        //        else if(sender.tag == 2){
        ////            self.nextButton?.hidden = true
        //            doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .Plain, target: self, action: #selector(PrepInfoVC.doneClick(_:)))
        //            doneButton!.tag = 2
        //        }
        let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .FlexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .Plain, target: self, action: #selector(PrepInfoVC.cancelClick))
        toolBar.setItems([cancelButton, spaceButton, doneButton!], animated: false)
        toolBar.userInteractionEnabled = true

        // Adds the toolbar to the view
        if university.tag == 0 {
            university.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
        }
        if industry.tag == 0 {
            industry.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
        }
        if graduationDate.tag == 0 {
            graduationDate.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
        }
    }

    func doneClick(sender:UIBarButtonItem) {
        if industry.tag == 0 {
            selectedIndustry = industryList[pickerView.selectedRowInComponent(0)]
            industry.text = selectedIndustry!.ind_name
            industry.tag = 1
            industry.resignFirstResponder()
        }else{
            selectedUni = uniList[pickerView.selectedRowInComponent(0)]
            university.text = selectedUni!.uni_name
            university.tag = 1
            university.resignFirstResponder()
        }
    }
    func cancelClick() {
        if industry.tag == 0 {
            industry.tag = 1
            industry.resignFirstResponder()
        }else {
            university.tag = 1
            university.resignFirstResponder()
        }
    }

    //MARK:- ImagePicker
    @IBAction func loadImageButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
        self.navigationController?.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = false
    }

    // MARK: - UIImagePickerControllerDelegate Methods
    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
        print(info)
        if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage {
            profileImageView.image = pickedImage.circle
            self.prepCompressedImage = UIImage.compressImage(pickedImage, compressRatio: 0.9)
            base64StringOf_my_image = appUtility.base64StringOfImage(self.prepCompressedImage)
//            self.viewWillAppear(false)
            fireNotification.pickedImage = pickedImage
            isDismissing = true
        }else{}
        imagePicker.delegate = nil
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true,completion: nil)
        isDismissing = true
    }
}

extension ProfileVC: UIPickerViewDelegate,UIPickerViewDataSource {

    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        if university.tag == 0 {
            return 1
        }else {
            return 1
        }
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

        if university.tag == 0 {
            return uniList.count
        }
        else {
            return industryList.count
        }
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        if university.tag == 0 {
            let uni = uniList[row]
            return String(uni.uni_name)
        }else {
            let ind = industryList[row]
            return String(ind.ind_name)
        }
    }
}

//MARK:- SearchVC
extension ProfileVC {
    func loadUni() {
      let userLoader = UserLoader()
        let params = ["":""]
        if PrepUtility.connectedToNetwork() {
            userLoader.tryUniversity(params, successBlock: { (university) in
                self.uniList = university!
            }) { (error) in
                if let err = error?.userInfo["NSLocalizedDescription"] {
                    appUtility.showAlert(err as! String, VC: self)
                }else {
                    appUtility.showAlert("Something went wrong", VC: self)
                }
            }
        }else {
            appUtility.showNoNetworkAlert()
        }
    }

    func loadIndustries() {
      let userLoader = UserLoader()
        if PrepUtility.connectedToNetwork() {
            userLoader.tryIndustry(["":""], successBlock: { (industry) in
                self.industryList = industry!
            }) { (error) in
                if let err = error?.userInfo["NSLocalizedDescription"] {
                    appUtility.showAlert(err as! String, VC: self)
                }else {
                    appUtility.showAlert("Something went wrong", VC: self)
                }
            }
        }else {
            appUtility.showNoNetworkAlert()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't initialize your UI in a viewWillLoad or similar method, I would say that your issue is coming from your device trying to get some more space.

You are probably out of memory and the system kill what it can (in your case your previous controller).

When you dismiss the image picker, your controller is reloading its views (with your initial values)

Answer (score 0):

i personally would save the .text of the label into variables previously declared (you are going to need them anyway) and in the viewDidAppear method assign the variables values to the textField.Text, when the view appear the first time they will appear empty, when you call the image picker you save the new values and then when the original view appears again it will assing the values you saved before.